# As a non-IT manager of IT folks, how do I represent familiarity with programming/technology?

Tags: resume, linkedin

I am a business-educated manager who works a lot with IT folks and programmers, and want to figure out what's the best way to represent this on the resume or linkedin.

I am not a programmer but understand how it works and many of the processes in software development. I have "developed" some of my own programs or made changes to script at a few times.

I am NOT an IT project manager (and that's not what I am applying for), but the industry/function I am interested in values technical skills a lot.

How do I represent deep familiarity - rather than hard skills - in an area?

Comment: `I have "developed" some of my own programs or made changes to script at a few times.` Why do you put "developed" in quotes like that. In a resume you should probably phrase it something like `Developed program to accomplish task X` or if you customized scripts maybe something like `Redefined server processes to meet project requirements` etc

Comment: Specify in your CV what IT tasks,activities and projects you managed directly and indirectly.

Answer (score 3):

No offense, but modifying a script or two and working with programmers means you know slightly more than nothing about programming.

If you've managed technical teams for years, say that. If you modified some scripts, say that. But don't sell some "deep familiarity" since that's meaningless. I'm deeply familiar with donuts, but I don't pretend that experience provides me some added ability to make donuts or manage bakers. I've worked a ton with HR people and sales people but I have no idea what their actual job entails.

Sell what actually matters - you've learned about the business aspects of making software, and (if appropriate) managing programmers, but most of all sell that you listen to your technical experts.

Comment: It's essentially impossible to obtain "deep familiarity" with programming without also acquiring the "hard skills". It's one of those fields where grasping the essential concepts almost necessitates going hands-on and programming with all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Be honest on your resume and in your interview. Talk about how you work on teams and how you interact with people. Talk about your experiences and accomplishments rather than programming skills and understanding of algorithms. Smart employers don't hire managers or leaders based on their technical skills, they hire them based on their soft skills and leadership potential.

If you're unfamiliar with some of the processes just find out what type of development they do and study the SDLC. Also the PMBOK (Project Management Body of Knowledge) is always useful.

When I didn't know something that my direct reports knew very well I wasn't afraid to be humble and just ask them to explain something to me. It made them feel valuable because they knew more than me and respected because I came to them as a source of information.